# PHPMailer issue Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my PHPMailer code since it's the first time I use it.
I'm trying to get the data from an HTML form using POST methond and send it as an email.
Also, I don't want to use SMTP

mail_handler.php

```
<?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    try {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
        $txtarea = $_POST['message'];
        $body = $name." says: " .$txtarea;
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->setFrom('loay.dayekh@gmail.com', 'louay');
        $mail->addAddress('loay.dayekh@gmail.com', $_POST['name']);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Contact email from Website';
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Comment: You are not using your Exception, you should be viewing `$e->getMessage()` in your `catch` block. This may be the same data as `$mail->ErrorInfo` but if so, that's more luck than judgement!

Answer (score 1):

This exact issue is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#could-not-instantiate-mail-function). It most likely means that you don't have a local mail server installed, or that your PHP installation is not configured correctly.

I don't know what you have against SMTP – it's both faster and safer to use SMTP to localhost than to use the `mail()` function.

Comment: The thing is I have a website hosted on godaddy and its giving me a headache with smtp. keeps giving me (We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.). so currently I'm using the old PHP mail() which is being received by Gmail but not Office 465.

Comment: Please read what the docs say about GoDaddy. That "We do not..." thing is not an error, it's just a "welcome" banner. Look at the rest of the transcript.